Clustering on clusters
I'm working on a problem where I need to categorize pore types in different sponges. To do this, I use the HDBSCAN clustering algorithm to create sponge-specific (or "local") clusters. I tune the hyperparameters for each sponge using a stability metric. Each clustering is based on 9 features and roughly 5,000 observations per sponge.
In addition to identifying local clusters, I'm interested in defining "global" pore types that might be common across multiple sponges. I don't know how many there could be, or if there are any at all.
My idea for this is to create a "fingerprint" for each local cluster and then cluster over all the fingerprints. Each fingerprint consists of 9 features representing the average raw value for each feature, along with 9 additional features representing the average absolute SHAP value for the corresponding feature, for 18 total features. The raw values characterize the cluster, while the SHAP values indicate which features are most significant.
I have several questions/concerns regarding this plan. Firstly, there are only 28 total clusters (across 8 sponges) and 18 features. I'm afraid this might be too sparse for clustering, especially with HDBSCAN on Euclidean distance. I read about dimensionality reduction through PCA/UMAP, but I have concerns regarding both. PCA only preserves linear relationships, and I'm not sure if that's suitable for my data. And UMAP, in my experience, often introduces artificial separations in the data.
Related to this, I'm not sure if the SHAP values are necessary to the fingerprint. In my mind, it's possible two clusters could have similar raw values but totally different SHAP values, and from an interpretation standpoint, those two clusters should not be considered the same. But it's all hypothetical, so I'd appreciate someone else's input.
Finally, I'm wondering if there's a better overall solution to defining global pore types than clustering on clusters. I'm averse to throwing all the different sponge data into one large dataset and clustering on that because that might produce false clusters that don't actually appear in any individual sponge.
